# Compound tag queries are redirected to the first tag on mobile

Tags: bug, tag-search

This happens (only) on my mobile phone with the full site version with

- Samsung's own browser "Internet"
- Chrome
- Opera

since a couple of hours. It definitely worked [2014-10-22 18:21:51Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500705/prolog-split-list-into-list-of-lists/26501157#comment41658601_26501157) (my last protocoled activity I see) and some more hours thereafter.

#### Problem

When clicking on a link like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+dcg one is redirected to the first tag thus to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog

#### Things that work

It works with Linux Firefox both directly and via WIFI when using the same phone as a hotspot, thus using the very same provider for the data transfer.

Comment: Works for me, I only see questions tagged with both. Tried Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7.

Comment: Just to be sure the cause wasn't a typo like in this Meta post, can you reproduce it with your phone and the link in this post?

Comment: @Stijn: Yes, in fact, after your first comment I did this.

Comment: Have you tried both WiFi and your data connection? This could be a proxy from your provider messing things up.

Comment: @Stijn: See above - its not the provider

Comment: You need to be logged in, see duped bug report.