# Content does NOT change when changing tabs on /tagged for a particular tag when NOT logged in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-search

The content (questions) of the /tagged page e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm?sort=votes&pageSize=15 doesn't change if I change the various tabs there, i.e. if I click on any tab: info or newest or featured or frequent or votes  or active or unanswered the URL query string changes but the content doesn't unless I'm logged in.

This happens for other tags as well: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15

NOTE: **To be able to reproduce this you need to be logged out** (i.e. not signed in)

Comment: Reproduced on the insecure site (http) as well before something blames navigating on the secure site.

Comment: [Related bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275311/multiple-tags-with-java-not-working#comment110174_275311).

Comment: Note: the UI now correctly reflects the available functionality (whether the various toggles are on/off, etc)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Requests from anonymous users to some of these routes were causing an unacceptably large performance hit a few days ago, potentially hurting the experience for many other users.

As a result, they were disabled for anonymous users. They may be re-enabled at some point when we have had time to implement a less drastic solution.

Comment: Maybe show some message at least? Or remove the tabs? As it stands, it's highly confusing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the tabs *are* removed now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters they were not removed when I reproduced it following the MSE report... well done! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The new version must've been rolled out between you reproducing the report and me posting my answer; when I posted about the related issue here on MSO the tabs were still there I think.

Comment: Could http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275155/compound-tag-queries-are-redirected-to-the-first-tag-on-mobile be caused by this?

Comment: So, status-bydesign?

Comment: @Stijn: yes, it is a dupe of the related bug report (a related change for the same root cause).

Comment: A good solutions for getting attention to unanswered questions hence improving page quality and SEO.

Comment: So this is status by design or just temporary?

Comment: It's status-bydesign *for now*, @Ooker.