# Sorting by votes when not logged in

Tags: bug, search

According to [Content does NOT change when changing tabs on /tagged for a particular tag when NOT logged in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when), when you are not logged in, you can't sort by votes, frequency etc.

For example, if you just go to the regular [questions page](//stackoverflow.com/questions) (when you're not logged in), it will, by default, sort by newest. In addition, the tabs for sort by frequent and sort by votes have disappeared. However, even when not logged in, we can still go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes but no tab would be highlighted.

Is this intentional behavior? If so, should we add the "votes" and/or "frequent" tabs back because the functionality is there when not logged in (and it is possible to sort by votes; it's just the link that has gone)?

Comment: Yeah, I see no reason to remove those buttons.