# Bounties should be visible for anonymous users ; now invisible

Tags: feature-request, bounty, anonymous-user

Bounties are no longer visible to anonymous users (edit:) on individual tags, probably since the various performance restrictions for anonymous users have been implemented.
Is this really a performance issue? By making bounties invisible to anonymous users there  is less incentive to join SO.

So my feature request:  Give featured-tab back to anonymous users.

Comment: [status-norepro]

Comment: @nicael: There is only [info] [newest] for [a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog).

Comment: Ah, yes. But I looked at [main] homepage, and there I can see featured tab.

Comment: @nicael: updated

Comment: I think this is [status-bydesign] for now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when

Comment: When you write feature request, you should clearly state the request. The title should then go "Bounties should be visible for anonymous users". As it is now it is not clear if this is what you want or the contrary.

Answer (score 21):

I'm not convinced the weight of seeing the feature tab will be very substantial in the decision for people to join.

Surely most non members don't think "*Hey, I can answer that and earn 50/100/X rep*".

I'm not saying *none* do, just not many, and that most non members join to ask a question, or they've spent some time here getting good answers, see they can add their own answers/comments and so join.

I joined just to upvote an answer that helped me greatly (and learned I couldn't up vote).

Comment: Did you ever upvote that answer once you got high enough rep?

Comment: @dav_i I did. 15 rep wasn't hard to earn :)

Comment: Shouldn't we also highlight bountied questions not just as "Hey, you could get extra points" but also "Look at this question that someone paid to spotlight" ?